waybar taskbar is not showing any icons [hyprland]
I don't understand. Nothing is showing up in the taskbar with waybar. I will share my config here.
"modules-center": ["wlr/taskbar"],

/* other stuffs in between */

"wlr/taskbar": {
        "icon-size": 12,
        "on-click": "activate",
        "on-click-right": "minimize",
        "format": "{icon}"
    },

below are my styles
#taskbar {
font-size: 4px;
margin-top: 6px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
background: #161320;
transition: none;
}

#taskbar button {
transition: none;
padding:6;
color: #B5E8E0;
background: transparent;
font-size: 16px;
border-radius: 2px;
}

#taskbar button.active {
    color: #B5E8E0 /*rgb(217, 135, 250);*/
}

EDIT: IMAGE Screenshot below


found that the bug is from Hyprland version 41.0. I build the latest 41.1 version and it fixed the issue.
